# Убрать и включить снова звук в Unity, AudioSource

Tags: c#, unity3d

При отключении AudioSource звук продолжал играть, лишь снижая громкость.

```
[RequireComponent(typeof(AudioSource))]
public class test : MonoBehaviour{
AudioSource audio1; 

void Start () {
    audio1 = GetComponent<AudioSource>();

  audio1.Stop();
}}
```

Comment: А есть какая-то связь между звуками у игрока и фоновой? А то что-то не очень понятно как она относится к делу...... А наполовину стихает может потому, что она  воспроизводится еще каким-нибудь источником

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как заметил Алексей Шиманский, у меня действительно был еще один AudioSource на фоне. Убрал его и проблема исчезла.